# How to restart the dask ui without killing jobs?

Tags: dask

If the dask ui is failing, is there a way of restarting it and reconnecting with the scheduler without killing jobs?

Comment: How is it failing?  It might be good to raise an issue if you're able to isolate the cause.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to debug this ... I'm not entirely sure where the detailed logs are landing. Nothing much is appearing in the console where I start the cluster.

Comment: Issue ended up being no bokeh installed. There was no warning ... I think might be a regression as warning was printed in previous versions.